# Regular expression to check if segment value contains ".HTML" extension. For ASP.NET routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Incoming url's for products will be mydomain.com/someproductname.html
I need to constrain a route so it would only handle such url's.
Making the check case insensitive too. If I don't enforce such restriction
than the below routes also pick-up URL requests like mydomain.com/level1category/ etc.
which should be handled by different route.

My routes that I want to constrain (Need to constrain the "ItemName" segment):

```
     routes.MapRoute(
     "ProductLink4", // Route name
     "{RootPointer}/{L1Cat}/{L2Cat}/{ItemName}", // URL with parameters
     new
     {
         controller = "Store",
         action = "ViewProduct",
     },
     new { controller = "Store", action = "ViewProduct" ItemName = @"[^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(html))" });

                routes.MapRoute(
    "ProductLink3", // Route name
    "{RootPointer}/{L1Cat}/{ItemName}", // URL with parameters
    new
    {
        controller = "Store",
        action = "ViewProduct",

    },
    new { controller = "Store", action = "ViewProduct" });

                routes.MapRoute(
    "ProductLink2", // Route name
    "{RootPointer}/{ItemName}", // URL with parameters
    new
    {
        controller = "Store",
        action = "ViewProduct",

    },
    new { controller = "Store", action = "ViewProduct" });

    }
```

Comment: You are planning on redirecting html traffic to asp.net?

Comment: No, I just want a particular route to handle URL request in the format of: mydomain.com/productname.html  This route would then pass the routedata value "productname.html" to an action method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup your route as

```
 routes.MapRoute(
 "ProductLink4", // Route name
 "{RootPointer}/{L1Cat}/{L2Cat}/{ItemName}.html",
 new
 {
     controller = "Store",
     action = "ViewProduct",
 },
```

Should constrain it to your .html fakefiles.

Answer (score 1):

```
string path = "mydomain.com/someproductname.html".ToLower();
```

With regex

```
bool flag = Regex.IsMatch(path, @"^.*\.(html)$");
```

Without Regex

```
bool flag = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path) == ".html";
```

Comment: This is not a real file, it does not exists. This is just a URL format that I wish to use.

Comment: Still it will work. Path.GetExtension works on URL also. tried myself. populates true in flag variable.